# How to SKIP a maven plugin execution from Eclipse Build Workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gruntjs

I am using a frontend-maven-plugin, [more info here](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin).

In order to run GRUNT tasks on maven build and, as I am using Eclipse, it builds the Workspace every time I change something in the code.

The problem is that the Eclipse build process executes the maven plugins every time, and it makes the process very slow. So I would like to know how can I skip the maven plugin execution from Eclipse Build workspace. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You probably have the option in menu "Project > Build automatically" checked. This makes Eclipse to rebuild after every file saved. Try to uncheck that (and build manually from it, using the menu "Project > Build")

Comment: Hi Tom, 
Thanks for your answer, but in my case, I really need to have this build automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes: You can tell Eclipse to ignore selected Maven plugins in either two ways:

- From Eclipse: Open Window > Preferences > Maven > Lifecycle mappings.
- From Maven: Add to your POM a `org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping` plugin.

Check out this [example](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html).

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for your answer, it seems to be exactely what I need, however it is not working. I've put in my pom the code listed on Ignore Plugin Goal chapter of the document you've sent me, however it still executing the Plugins. Here is my POM file -> https://codeshare.io/yKBWd.

Comment: I would prefer to have it on POM file to make it easy for new developers which may enter in the project in the future.

Comment: I was doing it wrong, I though I must put some of the maven goals on goal tag, but it must be the plugin gols. So in case of the frontend-maven-plugin, I've put the tags below and it works perfectly :). Thank you very much for your help!    

<goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
           <goal>npm</goal>
           <goal>bower</goal>
           <goal>grunt</goal>

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Little Santi's answer, I added this to my POM:

```
    ...
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>1.6</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                        <goal>npm</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```